# Download epub that's on iCloud

Tags: icloud, backup, data-transfer, books, epub

I have an epub that I unfortunatley deleted from my pc. It is however, still on iCloud and available to me on iBooks (when it's synced with icloud). I would like to download that epub again to my pc, but have found no method of doing so. Does anybody have a clue how to do this and is it even possible?

Thanks in advance,
Mark.

Comment: Can you email it from iBooks to yourself on the pc?

Answer (score 1):

Apple is famous for making things proprietary.

Since iBooks doesn’t actually use space on the hard drive there is no way to access the books from outside of iBooks.

I don’t see any way to share a file from iBooks on iOS.
I don’t have my Mac available at the moment, but I am going to bet you can’t share it from there either.

I guess you are stuck reading the file on iBooks.

Answer (score 0):

From iBooks click on the "Advanced" menu. There is a single option and that is to add ePub to your iBook library. If you don't have the "Advanced" menu go to Preferences under the ibooks menu and select "Advanced" and click the checkbox that appears.

Comment: How will that get it on his pc?  It has no iBooks app.

Comment: He said it was available to him on iBools.

Comment: These options aren't listed on my iPhone nor my iPad. Are you suggesting I use itunes for this? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Hey @TomGewecke I can email pdf's but for some reason no epubs, must be apple's piracy policy or something.

Comment: I didn't know you were referring to iOS.  Its not in your tags.